# JPlayer Starting Position Issue

Tags: android, cordova, html5-audio, jplayer

My Mobile App provides access to a large database of mp3 Audios. The App also allows the user to start an Audio from a specific position (basically last played position).

Whenever I try to run an audio from a given position, it first run the audio from the start for a second and then jumps to the given position.

I have also tried muting the audio but apparently mute also doesn't work after the first instance.

Here is how I am try to do this:

```
LastAudioPosition = 25;
$(this).jPlayer("play",LastAudioPosition);
```

Comment: Post your full jPlayer code please, also make a jsFiddle of the issue. I had this issue once but can't quite remember what problem was.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Please see my workaround in below post. Thanks for responding anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not finding a solution anywhere I ultimately settled with almost perfect solution. The idea is to mute the player for a small duration while the wrong part is played and then unmute it:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
  ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: gsLink
    }).jPlayer("play",gQFA_LastAudioPosition);
  },
  ended: function() {
    endFunction();
  },
  canplay: function() {
    $(this).jPlayer("mute");
    $(this).jPlayer("play");
    $(this).jPlayer("pause");
    $(this).jPlayer("play",gQFA_LastAudioPosition);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("unmute");
    }, 200);
},.................
```